# Creating custom MA envrionment

Tags: ray, rllib

I am looking for some guidance to building a multi agent dummy example. I've been trying to work through [Rllib documentation](https://docs.ray.io/en/latest/rllib-env.html#configuring-environments) , but I think I haven't understood the approach of how to create my own multi-agent environment.

I'd like to have several agents begin from different, random initial position x.
The dynamics governing each agent should governed by an differential equation like:

**derivative(x) = x + agent_action + noise**

The goal is for the agents to learn actions that will ultimately cause the x values of all agents to converge to one value.

Can I use the code stub provided in [multi_agent_env.py](https://github.com/ray-project/ray/blob/ced062319dca261b72b42d78048a167818c1f729/rllib/env/multi_agent_env.py) to implement my own MA environment?

For instance I create my own file MADummyEnv.py with

```
from ray.rllib.utils.annotations import PublicAPI
from ray.rllib.env.multi_agent_env import MultiAgentEnv
from ray.rllib.utils.typing import MultiAgentDict, AgentID

class MADummyEnv(MultiAgentEnv):
    ray.init()
    env = MyMultiAgentEnv()
    obs = env.reset()
    print(obs)

    new_obs, rewards, dones, infos = env.step(actions={"agent1": np.random.choice(action_list)}
```

and then implement the **init**, step, reset methods inside the MADummyEnv class. Is this correct?

Perhaps someone can point me into the general direction if I have the right idea or ideally provide an implementation of some custom multi agent environment for reference.

Answer (score 1):

[Here](https://github.com/ray-project/ray/blob/master/rllib/examples/env/rock_paper_scissors.py) you can find the implementation you asked.

Some things that might be worth considering:

- You mustn't call `ray.init` in the env file.
- The code you copied bellow the `class ...` is an example of how to use the env not what you should put in your env.